# Error parsing date string ''; 0: Data missing '\u0000'

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have this error :

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "Error parsing date string ''; 0: Data missing '\u0000'",
    "code" : 241,
    "codeName" : "ConversionFailure"
}
```

While running this query :

```
db.getCollection('creations').find({"$expr": {
    "$and": [
      {
        "$lte": [
          { "$dateFromString": { "dateString": "$datas.publishdate", "format": "%d/%m/%Y", "onNull":"" }},
          new Date().toISOString()
        ]
      }
    ],
  }})
```

The issue is that there's one record that have empty `publishdate` and I don't know what to do or to say **keep it if empty**

Comment: Are you sure `$datas.publishdate` is not null or empty?

Comment: Yet another example that it is always a bad idea to store `Date` values as strings.

Comment: Is it Null or is it empty?

Comment: @Viney some some empty and some are null

Comment: Could have used `onNull` if it were just nulls